# ER-модель Базы данных

Tags: база-данных, access, проектирование

Здравствуйте! Делаю ER-модель, которую задали в универе. Вот так она формулируется:

**Вуз. Отдел кадров.** Подразделения вуза. Штатное расписание (плановое распределение ставок и должностей по подразделениям). Сотрудники. Назначения, перемещения, увольнение сотрудников. Совмещение должностей.

Предпологаемые запросы:

- Найти людей, которые работали во всех подразделениях.
- Найти такие подразделения, в которых по штатному расписанию есть свободные ставки.
- Для всех людей показать их текущие оклады.
- Найти самые низкооплачиваемые должности и подразделения.
- Для указанного работника найти размер его оклада в сентябре 2009 года.
- Найти такие подразделения, которые требуют сокращения штатов согласно штатному расписанию, наличию сотрудников пенсионного возраста.

Саму модель сделал, выглядит она так:
[image: вуз, отдел кадров]
Не могу разобраться с одним моментом: если человек дважды устроиться на одну и ту же работу. Сейчас, с такой моделью это возможно... Каким образом запретить это?

Comment: Подразделения смотрятся странно. Сотрудников в них включать не планируется?

Comment: Ой, косяк, перезалью картунку

Comment: может добавить id должности у сотрудника

Comment: А смысл? Это все хранится в штатном расписании...